# Design issue in select tag in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap code but getting problem.

In large screen like desktop laptop screen it is good.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X027.jpg)

In responsive design like mobile screen select is having issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBYCW.jpg)

```css
.custom-select{
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem; 
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row g-4">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control custom-input" placeholder="Keyword">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <select class="form-select custom-select">
                      <option selected>All Job Category</option>
                      <option value="Web Designing">Web Designing</option>
                      <option value="Web Developer">Web Developer</option>
                      <option value="Testing">Testing</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <select class="form-select custom-select">
                      <option selected>All Job Locations</option>
                      <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
                      <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                      <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn custombtn-search">Search Now</button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: How did you test the mobile screen responsiveness? What's the screen width of your second image? Because I just tested your code and works fine even on 300px wide screen.

Comment: That's just a browser simulation. It should work on a phone

Comment: Second image is for small size for phone. I am surprised to see the output in chrome but in mozilla and edge it is working perfect. Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes guccibananaking99. I have realized it is browser issue.

Answer (score -1):

Are you checked with real mobile device ?

If you change layout to mobile view make sure to refresh browser, sometimes these things happen if you test without refresh.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have refreshed chrome browser a number of times but same issue is there but I have checked in Mozilla and edge browser; it is working perfect.